# How do I attach large files (>100 MB) and large videos (>16 MB) on Whatsapp?

Tags: whatsapp

I have seen people send very large files in Whatsapp chat groups.

---

The attached image 1 shows several large videos attached as files.

[image]

---

The image 2 shows the duration of a video whose size is 53 MB.

[image]

---

The largest I can attach is 16 MB video and 100 MB file.

I have more Whatsapp messages where videos larger than 16 MB are attached, but the Web version of Whatsapp doesn't show the video size.

OS: Windows 10 Home

Browser: Google Chrome Version 110.0.5481.178 (Official Build) (64-bit)

I follow the following steps in attempt to attach a video:

1. Log in to Whatsapp Web.
2. Select contact to send message to
3. Press "Attach" button
4. Select "Photos & Videos"
5. Select required video from file system
6. The following error message appears if I try to attach a video larger than 16 MB.

---

[image]

Comment: Please be more specific. Are your attemps the first attempt to send a message or you are forwarding a file that you have received? Please add the steps that you follow, the name and version of the operative system and web browser. Also add details about what happens when you try to send biggers files. If there is an error message add the textual error message.

Comment: Windows 10 Home, Trying to send video as the first attempt, Steps: 1. Login to Whatsapp web, 2. Select contact, 3. Press "Attach" button, 4. Select "Photos & Videos", 5. Select required video from file system. A brief message appears "1 video you tried attaching is larger than the 16 MB limit."

Comment: Google Chrome Version 109.0.5414.120 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Do you want me to add these details to the original question or you happy with the details in comment like now?

Comment: It's better that all the relevant details be added directly into the question by the OP (you)

Comment: By the way, it looks that Chrome requires to be updated,

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that my Chrome was a few days out-of-date. I have updated it to the latest version but surprisingly the original problem still fully persists. Also, I have added the details that you asked, into the question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks that the screenshots are showing that your contacts sent you the items using the Documents options instead of the Photos & Video option. The difference is that Documents should be downloaded and openeed using the device file manager, while the Photos & Video might be reproduced inside the WhatsApp client.

---

From [Send photos, videos, documents, stickers or contacts](https://faq.whatsapp.com/453914586839706/?helpref=hc_fnav&cms_platform=web)

Photos & Video

> There’s a 16 MB size limit for each video you send.

Documents

> The maximum allowed document size is 2 GB.

Comment: No, the case 2 is sent as a video and its size is 53 MB. So your answer isn't fully correct.

Comment: Sad that the Web version of Whatsapp doesn't show video size like the phone version does, so I can't attach a screenshot showing video size.

Comment: Whatsapp Web treats videos being attached as documents as videos, so still imposes the 16 MB limit. If I try to attach a video as a Document, it still doesn't allow to attach if it is larger than 16 MB. So what do you mean by "your contacts sent you the items using the Documents options"?

Comment: I think you should be able to see that the video in screenshot 2 is attached as a video, not a document. Because it can be viewed as a video without any need to downloaded to the filesystem and opened from there.